# Reshape arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to reshape two arrays into a certain shape

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)])
y = np.array([(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17, 18)])
```

I already used np.column_stack(x,y)

```py
np.column_stack((x,y))
```

to get:

```py
array([[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (10, 11, 12, 13, 14)],
       [(6, 7, 8, 9), (15, 16, 17, 18)]])
```

however, now i need the array to get to the following shape:

```py
array([[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)],
       [(6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18)]])
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Concatenate along axis 1

Comment: Are you showing parentheses vs brackets accurately?

Comment: @yatu I did, but since I am new it did not register it or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have an array of `tuples`, what you could do is add them along the first axis:

```
np.sum([x,y], axis=0)[:,None]

[[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)]
 [(6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me!

Comment: Note however that to define the inner arrays in a numpy array you should be using brackets not parenthesis. Otherwise you'll have an array of tuples and won't be able to apply most vectorised operations

Comment: @Stijn. You should select this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it

Answer (score 0):

Stacking introduces a new dimension. You want concatenation along the columns (*existing* axis 1):

```
np.concatenate((x, y), axis=1)
```

Comment: This gave me the following error:

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: @Stijn. Aahh. You're really using tuples? Why?

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
z = np.column_stack((x,y))
out = np.array([tuple(np.concatenate(z[0,:])), tuple(np.concatenate(z[1,:]))]).reshape((2,1))
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)])
y = np.array([(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17, 18)])
np.sum([x,y], axis=0)
```

array([(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18)],
      dtype=object)